# Video not clear when concatinate videos thogther using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 3 types of the video first is start video played when the video start, the main video which is the main content of the video and last is the end video I want to add them together they have different resolutions so I use a text file to write the videos name like this.

```
file start.mp4
file main.mp4
file end.mp4
```

then I use this command with FFmpeg

```
FFmpeg -f concat -i ffmpeg-sound.txt -c copy final_output.mp4
```

the problem is when I start watching the video the first video image is appearing in all the video duration I tried different player every one shows me a crashed photo but the sound is working fine.
also, the main video is created from mp3 file and image with subtitle it's not original or downloaded from anywhere and I want to concatenate them.
what i tried when i make some searches and i thought it's the problem that they have different resolution so i tried this command on both 3 videos to make them have the same resolution so no problem show after the concatenate

```
FFmpeg -y -i end.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts end.mp4.ts
```

and try to add the 3 files again with ts formate and the same problem shown too so please any help to solve this 
**Update**
i tried to use this command to change all the three videos to 1280x720

```
FFmpeg -i a.mp4 -vf scale=1280:720 a1.mp4
```

after testing the problem exactly i found that the first video only works then when it go to next video to show it, the screen is a freeze on the last image from the first video. I don't know why this problem even after i make them same scale! 
**here is the output of**

```
ffmpeg -i start.mp4 -i a.mp4 -i end.mp4
```

**output** this before edit all the videos resulution to 1280x720

```
    ffmpeg version N-89940-gb1af0e23a3 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'start.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Tunepro
    artist          : Kiran Khan
    album_artist    : Kiran Khan
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    description     : This video is about Tunepro
    keywords        : tunepro,new
  Duration: 00:00:03.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 863 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 729 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.7.100
  Duration: 00:05:21.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 188 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj444p(pc), 300x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 53 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'end.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Tunepro
    artist          : Kiran Khan
    album_artist    : Kiran Khan
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    description     : This video is about Tunepro
    keywords        : tunepro,new
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8051 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7923 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: the question is updated you can check them and thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main.mp4` file does not have the same width, height, and pixel format. Re-encode it to match the parameters of the other files to be concatenated:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i input.png -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]scale=1280x720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -shortest main.mp4
```

Then run your concat command.